# Openstack installation on Debian 8 networking fails

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm trying to install Openstack using [this](http://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-debian/common/conventions.html) manual.

I have two virtual nodes: controller1(controller) and cmp1(compute). Both of them have 2 interfaces. Eth0 of both nodes are in same bridge br0 on hypervisor and eth1 of both nodes are in br1.

Controller1:
eth0: 172.16.0.3/24
eth1: 10.0.0.3/24

Cmp1:
eth0 172.16.0.2/24
eth1: 10.0.0.2/24

Default route via 10.0.0.1/24.

Main hypervisor:
br0:172.16.0.1/24
br0:Public_IP_Also
br1:10.0.0.1/24

And I use name "public" instead of "provider" for flat network.

I've been walking through the manual and stuck on Neutron configuration.

If I'm trying to run `openstack network agent list` I see:

```
openstack: 'network' is not an openstack command. See 'openstack --help'.
Did you mean one of thease?
network create
network delete
network set
network show
```

If I'm trying to create network via `openstack network create --share --provider-physical-network public --provider-network-type flat public` I see next error:

```
openstack network create: error: unrecognized arguments: --provider-physical-network --provider-network-type flat public
```

Also, there's no `openstack subnet create` command.

What logs and configuration files should I show here?

I found [this](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/98823/openstack-network-create-error-unrecognized-arguments/) question, but there's no answer.

I've deleted all neutron packages and reinstall again, dropped and re-created database - but nothing helps.

UPD:
I found that there is no `network_agent.py` and some more files in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openstackclient/network/v2/ , but there are in [sources on git](https://github.com/openstack/python-openstackclient/tree/master/openstackclient/network/v2). What package did I forget to install? Or is it a bug?

Hope for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bad .deb package.

So, the answer is to use pip.

```
pip install python-openstackclient --upgrade
```

After that `openstack network agent list` works fine and network creates as it should be.